# Table LateX doesn't show up in the document

Tags: latex

For some reason my code is not reproducing the table I wanted in the document. Only a bold line shows up but no cells or text. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,final]{article}
%\doctype{Thesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[algo2e, ruled, vlined]{algorithm2e} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{table}[]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Date   & Luis Lacalle Pou                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 & Date & Alberto Fernandez                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             \\ \hline
May 21  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Announces the return to in-person classes strategy... \\ “We are taking this decision because we are convinced that the risk is minimal. We wouldn’t be doing it otherwise”(Infobae, 2020)\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                        & April 25  & Announcement of the extension of the lockdown... (Casa Rosada, 2020a) \\ \hline
June 25  & Press conference speech... (CED Uruguay, 2020)                           & June 20   & Speech during Argentina’s Flag Day...  (Casa Rosada, 2020b)                                                                                                                                                                                                           \\ \hline
July 12  & Lacalle Pou justified ... (Lacalle Pou, 2020a) & July 18   & Press conference along with Buenos Aires’ ... (Casa Rosada, 2020c)                                                                                                                                             \\ \hline
July 22      & Press conference ... (Lacalle Pou, 2020b)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        & July 31   & Speech directed to ... (Casa Rosada, 2020d)   \\ \hline
September 22 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Speech for the General Assembly in the UN.  “Our country’s answer to the pandemic (...) \\ (Lacalle Pou, 2020c)\end{tabular}                                                                                                                            & August 28 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Announcement of the extension of the quarantine restrictions. \\ “It has been almost 100 days ... . (Casa Rosada, 2020e)\end{tabular}             \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This is how it looks in my LaTeX doc [image: latex].

And this is how I would like it to look[image: Original]

This is how it looks in my LaTeX doc [image: latex].

And this is how I would like it to look[image: Original]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a bold line, that literarily is your table ... just scaled down sooooooo much by `\resizebox` that you can't see it. That's one of the many reasons you should never use `\resizebox` for elements which contain text. Other reasons are suboptimal choice of letter shapes and a ransom letter appearance to the final document with all the different font sizes.

Other problems:

- `\begin{document}` is missing
- By using `l` columns for your table and then even wrapping the verrrrrrrrrrrry long lines into additional tables with `c` columns, you are very efficiently telling latex to never ever break lines in your table. Instead you could use a column of fixed with, or - easier -  use the `tabularray` package with an `X` column which will automatically calculate the width
- no floating specifier like `[htbp]` is given

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,final]{article}
%\doctype{Thesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[algo2e, ruled, vlined]{algorithm2e} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{geometry}
%\geometry{hmargin=1cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
%\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tblr}{|l|X[l]|l|X[l]|}
\hline
Date   & Luis Lacalle Pou                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 & Date & Alberto Fernandez                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             \\ \hline
May 21  & Announces the return to in-person classes strategy... “We are taking this decision because we are convinced that the risk is minimal. We wouldn’t be doing it otherwise”(Infobae, 2020)                                                                                                                                                                                  & April 25  & Announcement of the extension of the lockdown... (Casa Rosada, 2020a) \\ \hline
June 25  & Press conference speech... (CED Uruguay, 2020)                           & June 20   & Speech during Argentina’s Flag Day...  (Casa Rosada, 2020b)                                                                                                                                                                                                           \\ \hline
July 12  & Lacalle Pou justified ... (Lacalle Pou, 2020a) & July 18   & Press conference along with Buenos Aires’ ... (Casa Rosada, 2020c)                                                                                                                                             \\ \hline
July 22      & Press conference ... (Lacalle Pou, 2020b)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        & July 31   & Speech directed to ... (Casa Rosada, 2020d) \\ \hline
September 22 & Speech for the General Assembly in the UN.  “Our country’s answer to the pandemic (...)  (Lacalle Pou, 2020c)                                                                                                                       & August 28 & Announcement of the extension of the quarantine restrictions.  “It has been almost 100 days ... . (Casa Rosada, 2020e)          \\ \hline
\end{tblr}%
%}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Your LaTeX expertise is quite astonishing! your suggestion worked but now the table extends beyond the page and does not translate into the next one. I tried using the longtable package but it doesn't work. I will write a new question about it.